# May I install temporarily programs during guest session

Tags: software-installation, guest-session

I want to try Ubuntu with my students only in guest session. It is possible to temporarily install programs (e.g. Bluefish) in this session? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No the guest session does not have permission to install programs not even temporarily. If you log in as a user that installs packages you could say install bluefish before and they log in and it will be there. If you need to install software after say a student logs in it can be a bit tough. If you have https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH you could ssh into the machines the students temporarily log onto and isntall the programs using apt package manager on the command line and then you can uninstall it if you do not want it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Comment: Thank you! It is a pity. It would be nice if they could try to install it yourself, in guest session...